# Avast opening application in sandbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5

I have a .net application. I create a setup project for my application. Whenever I click on my `setup.exe` file it is blocked by the antivirus e.g AVAST.
Can anyone tell me how can i increase the reputation of my application ? or i have to license my application?

Answer (score 0):

Well i am not sure, but i think avast blocked your app because it is an .exe extension, so avast recognizes the app and thinks it could be harmful, if you can't change (.exe)which i think you cant. Now what you could try is to give some information about your app like the the designer... This fixed the problem for me but it is possible that it will not fix the problem for you. Just give it a try.

Comment: where to mention the designer ?